# Text Randomizer (+ positioning)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, random

I am making a site that's (simply said) a parody of Google, but I need one thing to finish it.

I am looking for a script that makes random (but set by me) sentenses, that I am able to position (in a `<div>` , possibly)

It would be best if I could set as many sentenses as I want to.
I've already found one, but it is only able to hold 2 sentenses and I can't possition it.

Also, I am a newbie in html, so please don't use those hardcore IT terms :D

Comment: You'll need to know some Javascript, but you can use https://baconipsum.com/ to generate random text. It's what I use at work to generate test data.

Comment: Where are you getting the sentences from? Can they be stored in the script?

Comment: mister_rampage: Well - you propably didnt get what I meant - I want it so when you open the page, it allways chooses random text (that I write in).

Comment: Greg: I am going to write the sentenses myself, anything I want to. So yeah, they can be written in the script (if I am able to edit them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you're after. Hopefully you can extrapolate from here to fit your existing code.

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div id="container"></div>

        <script>
            var sentences = [
                "sentence 1",
                "sentence 2",
                "sentence 3"
            ];

            window.onload = function() {
                var div = document.getElementById('container');

                div.innerHTML = sentences[Math.floor(Math.random()*sentences.length)];
            };

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works pretty nicely but is there a way to put it into a <div>? When I try to put it into the one I have, it doesn't show up nor does it randomize, no text at all.
<div class="fbar" style="position:absolute;height:41px;width:100%;bottom:0px;background-color:#f6f1f1;bottom:0px;margin-left:0px;margin-right:0px;margin-bottom:0px;margin-top:0px;">*the script*</div> -- This may help, it's the one I am trying to put it in.

Comment: What would you like put into a div?  This code places a random sentence inside the `<div id="container"></div>`

Comment: Oh, now I get it, I will need to do id="container into the div I am putting it in. Thanks."

Comment: Any Idea how to get the text centered though?

Comment: Use some CSS for that. `text-align: center` should do it